# Are these MOSFETs the same? Do the two differences in the datasheet matter?

Tags: datasheet

When trying to select parts the supplier has two P-channel MOSFETs listed. One an [AO3401](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3401.pdf) and the other an [AO3401A](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810171817_Alpha---Omega-Semicon-AO3401A_C15127.pdf). The are only two differences between them. One in the general description. One additional line added to Dynamic Parameters. Further everything is identical. Do those two differences matter or does it mean the AO3401A cannot be used in PWM applications? Can you use the two chips interchangeably and it wouldn't matter if your application is PWM or not?

Difference1:

> This device is suitable for use as a load switch or in PWM applications. (AO3401)

vs

> This device is suitable for use as a load switch or other general applications. (AO3401A)

Difference2:

[image: Additional Dynamic Parameter on AO3401]AO3401

Comment: if the only difference between the part numbers is a suffix, it's very likely that one is an improved version of the other. Unless you're doing something very strange, either will work in any application where one will.

Comment: No, I am using it as a load switch. I was just confused when I saw that and thought I'd ask just to be sure in case I run across this is the future and the A version is the only one available. And if the the A is an improved version, great.

Comment: _”AO3401A cannot be used in PWM applications”_ Why would that be? Check for and compare switching times for both.

Comment: any questions from my answer?  @winny obviously no difference except description

Comment: To me it sounds like the non-A version must always be used as a switch. Either a load switch or for PWM. The A version may be used in non-switching applications (possibly it can be used as a linear regulator pass element, for example). I am basing this entirely on the wording in the question. I didn't actually read the datasheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All datasheets are subject to change without notice ( with a few exceptions to very high-end users)
*The Pulsed Diode performance is implied for all diodes but was a minor addition to Rev A.then later deleted without the suffix and also deleted from Rev C.  So there must have been at least one reliability issue or reason why it was omitted.*

http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3401.pdf Rev 6: Feb. 2011 and
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810171817_Alpha---Omega-Semicon-AO3401A_C15127.pdf    Rev 3: Mar. 2011

http://www.tdldz.com/Upload/AOSMOSFETs%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD/AO3401C%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E6%89%8B%E5%86%8C%E8%A7%84%E6%A0%BC%E4%B9%A6-15410088118.pdf  aosmd Rev.1.0: March 2019

Notice LCSC is a good distributor but the document is still published by AOSMD with the A suffix being a later Rev date but lower letter (?) are both the same contents but the file name includes C which is a different part and not listed on AOSMD site but seems to an AOSMD document exclusive to the TDLDZ distributor.

The AO3401C is only listed by another Chinese Distributor is a slightly different part as it shows a threshold at twice the level of the A part but with a bi-zener Gate clamp limited to 20V yet Vds is rated for 30V with slightly higher RdsOn, Rg faster delay but slower Off times . Overall perhaps a more reliable part.

**strong text**

It is not known for sure when gate Zener clamps were added with a small not shown gate resistance of a few ohms but this significantly improves the ESD and OVP protection on Vgs.  Not only can over Vgs cause fail open and ESD fails shorted but partial damage can degrade the input and output impedance.

This is an extremely important lesson learned for all graduates and DIY enthusiasts that due to the extremely low Cin and extremely high Rin, all FETs are easily wounded without the circuit protection during handling, soldering, etc.

However low current diodes have high ESR, Rs or "bulk resistance" and high current diodes and Zeners add capacitance that compromises rise time so the choice of embedded or added Zener depends on why it is added (handling or circuit transients) as careful selection to limit voltage, current and slew rate reduction are each affected.

**"So consider all requirements in your specs. or expectations"**

Answer (score 2):

A PWM application is a general application. And that the older datasheet does not mention general applications does not imply that those would not be suitable. In any case, the description has no numbers and does not really matter.

There are two other documented differences: the marking, and the test conditions for some R<sub>DS(ON)</sub> entries.

It is possible that these devices are different. But it is also plausible that they use the same die, and that the only difference is in how they are tested.

If you design your circuit to the datasheet specifications, then you can use both.

Please note that A&O recommends that both can be replaced with the newer AOSS21311C, which has different characteristics, but which probably would work fine with your application.